# A Class/Struct that holdes multiple child classes, holding multiple grandchildren classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I am looking for some **advice on design/concept**. I know how to create classes. But not sure if ***THIS*** is the way to do what I want to do. Is my concept on the right track, or should I create a STRUCT, or something else?

**Needs:**

1. Load it from a database (No problem)
2. Load it on an ASP.NET page (No problem)
3. Caching??? As looping through (POSTBACK) each Bag on a form, HOPEFULLY not having to go back to the database every time I need to go to the next BAG or ITEM with each subsequent page request.

**Concept:** (This is a concept, not real code. I don't need help with the coding, thanks)

```
public class CarTrunk
{
    CarTrunk.Load(int TrunkID);
    CarTrunk.Weight;
    CarTrunk.Bags[]; //Should this be a collection of Bag classes?
    foreach(Bag bags in CarTrunk.Bags) {
        Bags.Weight;
        Bags.TypeOfBag;
        Bags.Items[]; //Should this be a collection of Item classes?
        foreach(Item i in Bags.Items) {
            i.Name;
            i.Weight;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

surely you won't have a foreach in the class definition.

usually with modern ORMs like NHibernate or EF you can handle multi-level entity hierarchies, there are so many examples around, for example, this one has a 3 level structure like yours, check question and all answers ;-)

[Return class from nested collection using NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000783/return-class-from-nested-collection-using-nhibernate)

ah, **yes** you better to use collections instead of raw Arrays for `Bags` and `Items`

Comment: Ok, I put a test together. Basically three classes.

Comment: Sorry... it submitted before I was done. So I have three classes: Trunk Class (Gets the trunk, by ID), Bag class, and Items class.

Trunk class is a class instance. The rest are dictionary objects of classes. Is this overkill? Should it not be done that way? I don't quite understand memory usage, and/or logic. I come from a 15 year Classic ASP background. You look through records, get more records, get more records. So this is new to me. I got it working, but I don't like being uncomfortable with my process. Thanks for your time.